# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when switching views of SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

I'm encountering a problem with a Swift/Spritekit game I am creating.

When I attempt to switch from a launch screen view, to a view which displays the contents of the game I am creating.

This is when *(to my dismay)* a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error displays.

I have done a bit of debugging myself, and the app loads fine if I comment out these two lines of code:

```
anchorNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (circle.frame.size.height / 1000))
```

and:

```
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ball.frame.size.width / 2))
```

It all would be dandy and fine if I were able to just figure a way around including these lines, but of corse, they are crucial to the game functioning.

Would loading the physicsBody into the memory of the app cause the crash? Or is there something else I should include.

For reference, here is where I attempt to stitch views from my main screen to the screen which displays the game:

```
        if let name = touchedNode.name {

            if name == "goimage" {

                let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1)
                let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: doors)
            }
```

I also have Crashlytics installed, if that makes an ounce of a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that anchorNode and ball have been created when the statements execute?

Comment: Im afraid I don't quite follow. I add the ball and anchorNode to the view before I apply the physicsBody to them with `self.addChild(ball)` and `self.addChild(anchorNode)` if that is what you mean. Would this have an impact on the crash?

Comment: If ball or anchorNode are nil, you would get the error message you are seeing. Did you look at their values in the debugger?